# Creating x ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I use a variable class which stores an integer. If the integer is 13, I need 13 arraylists to be created. Any idea as to how I would do this?

This is what is in my while loop:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> list + count = new ArrayList<>();
```

With the following:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myLists.add(newList);
}
```

Let's say I need the integer 9 to go into the 3rd array list and the integer 3 to go to the 2nd array list. How would i do that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by putting a `+` sign on the left side of an assignment?  That isn't legal Java.  Are you inventing your own syntax and hoping the compiler can figure it out?

Comment: I'm trying to get multiple array lists as stated above. I thought the + sign would make the array list names be (list1, list2 .. list13)

Comment: You can create an array of `ArrayList` (`ArrayList<T>[]`) or an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` (`ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>`).  I don't know what `T` is.  You can create an array of 13 `ArrayLists` by saying `new ArrayList<T>[13]`, but then you have to create each `ArrayList` in a loop, since this will be an array of nulls.

Comment: _You cannot create variable names dynamically in Java_.  If you want _n_ objects, you can create an array, `ArrayList`, or some other data structure.  Don't do it by trying to create a large number of variables.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?

You can create an ArrayList of ArrayLists. So something like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

for(int i = 0; i < numOfLists; i++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myLists.add(newList);
}
```

That way you'll have myLists with all the lists you created.

Comment: Let's say now I need to add the integer 3 to the 3rd ArrayList. How would I do that?

Comment: Right after you initialize `newList`, you could do:
`newList.add(i+1)`

Comment: How would you know which ArrayList? Like how do I know which ArrayList is newList?

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve, but you know which list is which because of the order you created them. So the first ArrayList would be accessed in `myLists` by doing something like `myLists.get(0)` and if you want the first element in the first ArrayList in myLists, you could do `myLists.get(0).get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

By concatinating the variable to make another variable name is not possible. The compiler should already told you about this. You can accomplish this by using another `ArrayList`

```
List<List<Integer[]>> mainList = new ArrayList<List<Integer[]>>();
        for(int i = 0; i  < 13; i++){

            mainList.add(new ArrayList<Integer[]>());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify each of the `ArrayList` by a name you could use a `Map`.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer[]>> listsMap = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
   listsMap.add("list" + i, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Then, if you need to add an integer to a particular list you could do this:

```
listsMap.get("list3").add(new Integer[]{3});
```